# Not able to Install Android Studio on ubuntu

Tags: android-studio

running the studio.sh file is giving me the following error

```
root@ezio-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:/usr/local/android-studio/bin#./studio.sh
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0

Start Failed: Internal Error. Please report to https://https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:39)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/lib/i386/libawt_xawt.so: libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1845)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1636)
at java.awt.Toolkit$3.run(Toolkit.java:1634)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1633)
at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1668)
at java.awt.Cursor.<clinit>(Cursor.java:195)
at javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit.<clinit>(HTMLEditorKit.java:623)
at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.<clinit>(UIUtil.java:97)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.start(PluginManager.java:71)
... 6 more


Also, an UI exception occurred on attempt to show above message:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit
at java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:593)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:336)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:312)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:291)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:106)
root@ezio-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:/usr/local/android-studio/bin# ^C
root@ezio-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:/usr/local/android-studio/bin#
```

Comment: "Please report to https://https://code.google.com/p/android/issues" We really can not fix that error without looking at the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking what is the current default java version in terminal`java -version`
If your not using recommended version type `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and insert the number that points to java-8-openjdk , java-7-oracle or java-8-oracle.